# Why does vmin and vmax not update the colorbar when using seaborn?

Tags: python

```
    ax = sns.heatmap(df1, norm = LogNorm(), cmap = 'jet', vmin = 100000, vmax = 50000000)
```

When I add in vmin and vmax parameters, the colorbars scale is unchanged. What would cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this sample:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

minX, maxX, minY, maxY = -2., 2., -2., 2.
x = np.linspace(minX, maxX, 100)
y = np.linspace(minY, maxY, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.sin(X**2 + Y**2) / (X**2 + Y**2) + 1

sns.heatmap(z, norm = LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=2), cmap = 'jet',)

plt.show()
```

Here z.min()=0.78, z.max()=2.0.

vmin=1 cuts values (0.78...1.0) and thus creates a ring marked with 10^0:
[image]

Comment: YES. Thank you! I didnt realize you had to put it inside the lognorm parameter.